# How to send emails according to user request in python?

Tags: python, email

How do i send an email whenever a user requests it?. I thought on a script that sends mails every hour with some content relevant for the recipients, but I dont like the idea of spamming mail to other people. So i would like to send this mail whenever the recipients wants it. For example if this user sends me a mail with a keyword, i would like the sript to run and send the mail back with the content already made up. So, there is no spam and information is sent in a more efficient way.
I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex and broad question.

First off, you would need a server or your PC to have the script running all the time or periodically fire off via [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Secondly, you would need to keep some kind of job queue where you would register that a user has sent you an email requesting that you send them one in response. There are well developed and complex job queues like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html), but you could potentially do with something less complex - maybe a Google Sheets table.

Thirdly, you would need to parse emails you receive in order to get the keywords and email addresses. If you go the gmail + google sheets route, you could do it with some custom code probably, but otherwise you would need to implement email checking on your PC or server. Once you parse them, you add them to the jobs queue.

Finally, you need to provide email access to your Py script - meaning SMTP login. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) have more on this.

As you can see, there are a lot of things to consider and implement, so you maybe better off trying to narrow down your question a bit. :)

Comment: Im sorry for not being clear. I already have a remote server in Digital Ocean with the code included. I was thinking on using crontab to send the mail every hour but as i said, that is not the idea. I would like my script to be run according to user requirements which in this case is the user mail.

Comment: No problem, you can edit the question to provide more info. :)

Comment: Well, that setup solves point number one. You are left with the next 3, and unfortunately, this is not the best place to seeks such answers. You can check out some of the docs I linked. 

A good starting point  could be Django (a web framework) with Celery.
Still, what you want to do requires quite a bit of overhead and code. :)